# How to generate a foreach grid table

Tags: php, html, foreach, html-table

I have this code that I am trying to make into a grid table. What I have so far generates the results all in one column. How can I make it so that when the first column reaches 10 rows a new column is created?

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Players</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php if( ( $Players = $Query->GetPlayers( ) ) !== false ): ?>
    <?php foreach( $Players as $Player ): ?>
<tr>
<td align=center><?php echo "<img src=https://crafatar.com/avatars/".$Player."/?helm&size=32>
              <p align=center>".$Player."</p>"; ?></td>
</tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php else: ?>
    <tr>
    <td>No players Online.</td>
    </tr>
    <?php endif; ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Add a counter variable `$i` that is increased on every iteration. Then you can use the condition `($i % 10 === 0)` to check if you need to create a new row. Just output a `</tr><tr>` in this case.

Comment: The OP was asking about multiple columns per 10 rows, not multiple rows per 10 columns. In this case, you would need to fill an array ahead of time before displaying the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case you mentioned, you would need to gather all of the data before printing the table, build an array and do some mathematics. This is due to how the Table and it's children are Modeled. I would recommend switching to columns first, then rows if possible - like it was mentioned in the comments.

In the recommended case, it would be as follows:

```
$i = 1;
// start first row
echo "<tr>";

foreach($Players as $Player){

    echo "<td>" . $Player . "</td>";

    // do we need a new row?
    if($i % MAX_COLUMN_NUMBER === 0){
        echo "</tr><tr>";
    }

    // increase counter
    $i++;

}

// end final row
echo "</tr>";
```

If you replace `MAX_COLUMN_NUMBER` with 3 and have, for example, 10 items in the `$Players` variable, it would look like this:

```
╔════╤═══╤═══╗
║ 1  │ 2 │ 3 ║
╠════╪═══╪═══╣
║ 4  │ 5 │ 6 ║
╟────┼───┼───╢
║ 7  │ 8 │ 9 ║
╟────┼───┼───╢
║ 10 │   │   ║
╚════╧═══╧═══╝
```

Comment: Thank you so much Brandon, This helped me immensely!